# How to parse a complex Json which is a List of Maps in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

I need to parse a complex json in flutter(as I am new).I have done quite number of things but somewhere down the line where I want to get the result ,I am getting as NULL.I really don't understand why?

Also to generate the PODO file I am using https://app.quicktype.io/ website,but there is on the right hand side I am don't understand what is this "Put encoder & decoder in Class".I tried to google but couldnt understand much about it as this website can convert JSON to many languages.

This is the JSON structure(including this link or else it becomes too long,the answer): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h_T6zmubYnqQFxPg944F-XJ4K2dQ2sFQGxmQNiUKK8o/edit?usp=sharing

The PODO file is

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final moviesPage = moviesPageFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<MoviesPage> moviesPageFromJson(String str) => List<MoviesPage>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => MoviesPage.fromJson(x)));

String moviesPageToJson(List<MoviesPage> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class MoviesPage {
    MoviesPage({
        this.movieBanners,
        this.popular,
        this.genre,
    });

    List<MovieBannerElement> movieBanners;
    List<MovieBannerElement> popular;
    List<MovieBannerElement> genre;

    factory MoviesPage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MoviesPage(
        movieBanners: json["movie_banners"] == null ? null : List<MovieBannerElement>.from(json["movie_banners"].map((x) => MovieBannerElement.fromJson(x))),
        popular: json["popular"] == null ? null : List<MovieBannerElement>.from(json["popular"].map((x) => MovieBannerElement.fromJson(x))),
        genre: json["genre"] == null ? null : List<MovieBannerElement>.from(json["genre"].map((x) => MovieBannerElement.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "movie_banners": movieBanners == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(movieBanners.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "popular": popular == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(popular.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "genre": genre == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(genre.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class MovieBannerElement {
    MovieBannerElement({
        this.genreName,
        this.movieId,
        this.title,
        this.tags,
        this.genres,
        this.thumbnail,
        this.posterLink,
        this.platform,
        this.worldwide,
        this.createdAt,
    });

    String genreName;
    String movieId;
    String title;
    List<String> tags;
    List<GenreEnum> genres;
    List<String> thumbnail;
    String posterLink;
    Platform platform;
    int worldwide;
    DateTime createdAt;

    factory MovieBannerElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MovieBannerElement(
        genreName: json["genre_name"] == null ? null : json["genre_name"],
        movieId: json["movie_id"] == null ? null : json["movie_id"],
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        tags: json["tags"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
        genres: json["genres"] == null ? null : List<GenreEnum>.from(json["genres"].map((x) => genreEnumValues.map[x])),
        thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["thumbnail"].map((x) => x)),
        posterLink: json["poster_link"] == null ? null : json["poster_link"],
        platform: json["platform"] == null ? null : platformValues.map[json["platform"]],
        worldwide: json["WORLDWIDE"] == null ? null : json["WORLDWIDE"],
        createdAt: json["createdAt"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "genre_name": genreName == null ? null : genreName,
        "movie_id": movieId == null ? null : movieId,
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "tags": tags == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
        "genres": genres == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(genres.map((x) => genreEnumValues.reverse[x])),
        "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(thumbnail.map((x) => x)),
        "poster_link": posterLink == null ? null : posterLink,
        "platform": platform == null ? null : platformValues.reverse[platform],
        "WORLDWIDE": worldwide == null ? null : worldwide,
        "createdAt": createdAt == null ? null : createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}

enum GenreEnum { THE_5_E10_BFDF923885_A2149948_FF, THE_5_E10_BFE1923885_A214994907, THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994903, THE_5_E10_BFDE923885_A2149948_FB, THE_5_E10_BFDC923885_A2149948_F7, THE_5_E10_BFE2923885_A21499490_B, THE_5_E10_BFE2923885_A21499490_D, THE_5_E10_BFDF923885_A2149948_FD, THE_5_E10_BFDE923885_A2149948_F9, THE_5_E10_BFE3923885_A214994911, THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994905, THE_5_E10_BFE1923885_A214994909, THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994901 }

final genreEnumValues = EnumValues({
    "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFDC923885_A2149948_F7,
    "5e10bfde923885a2149948f9": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFDE923885_A2149948_F9,
    "5e10bfde923885a2149948fb": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFDE923885_A2149948_FB,
    "5e10bfdf923885a2149948fd": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFDF923885_A2149948_FD,
    "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFDF923885_A2149948_FF,
    "5e10bfe0923885a214994901": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994901,
    "5e10bfe0923885a214994903": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994903,
    "5e10bfe0923885a214994905": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE0923885_A214994905,
    "5e10bfe1923885a214994907": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE1923885_A214994907,
    "5e10bfe1923885a214994909": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE1923885_A214994909,
    "5e10bfe2923885a21499490b": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE2923885_A21499490_B,
    "5e10bfe2923885a21499490d": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE2923885_A21499490_D,
    "5e10bfe3923885a214994911": GenreEnum.THE_5_E10_BFE3923885_A214994911
});

enum Platform { YOUTUBE, POPCORNFLIX }

final platformValues = EnumValues({
    "popcornflix": Platform.POPCORNFLIX,
    "youtube": Platform.YOUTUBE
});

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
    Map<T, String> reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
}
```

The point is when I tick the "Put encoder & decoder in Class" the initial lines:

```
List<MoviesPage> moviesPageFromJson(String str) => List<MoviesPage>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => MoviesPage.fromJson(x)));

String moviesPageToJson(List<MoviesPage> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

disappear.I mean how to parse the JSON

I have created the service file like this:

class ServicesForMoviesPage {
static const String url =
"https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v3/home?pageLocation=movies&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
"user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

```
  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForPopularMovies() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    List<MovieBannerElement> popularObjectList = [];
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there for movies Page");
      final List<MoviesPage> moviesPageObjectList =
          moviesPageFromJson(res.body);

      print("Movies page.........pppppppppppppppp................");

      for (int i = 0; i <= moviesPageObjectList.length; i++) {
        popularObjectList = moviesPageObjectList[i].popular;
        print("PopularObjectList");
        print(popularObjectList);
      }

      List<String> popular_movie_Id = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < popularObjectList.length; i++) {
        popular_movie_Id.add(popularObjectList[i].movieId);
      }
      return popular_movie_Id;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Here moviesPageObjectList[i].popular down the line is returning null.But why?

Also it says:

```
final moviesPage = moviesPageFromJson(jsonString);
```

to parse the data,but it is actually:

```
 final List<MoviesPage> moviesPageObjectList =
          moviesPageFromJson(res.body);
```

It is precisely here that List of MoviesPage and the subsequent stuff really killing me,as I printed and saw,a list of list gets generated and then a list of NULL elements.

Is there a simpler way to parse JSON data,like converting into XML or anyother format and doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Factory function like this would do

```
 factory MovieBannerElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       
        try {
          MovieBannerElement object = MovieBannerElement(
        movieId: json['movie_id'],
        title: json['title'],
        ...
      );

      return object;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

But I couldn't find the 'genreName' the json shared.